# Compare/match/find similar value between data frame/matrix in R

Tags: r, compare, match

I am very confused on value matching in R. I ve tried match, %in%, which, round .. and etc. However no luck to compare 2 data sets each other.
Some part of my data intersect on 3D space. Sample coordinates are stored in data frame as below :

(X,Y,Z)  (100.234,150.656,35.678)

Data set is huge. When I compare data sets with %in% function. it does not response true.
I've read some forum pages and somebody mention floating point values. How to fix the matching problem in R? Any sample R code for matching 2 data set which intersect some parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the R-section!

I don't know exactly what type of data your are trying to work with nor the purpose of the comparison of your data.

However here are some ways you can find that information out (with slightly different outputs):

```
xdat<-c(10,13,32,17)
ydat<-c(32,17,10,5,19)


> which(xdat %in% ydat)
[1] 1 3 4

> match(xdat,ydat)
[1]  3 NA  1  2

> xdat %in% ydat
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

> unlist(sapply(xdat,function(x) grep(x,ydat)))
[1] 3 1 2
```

Also, [this short R reference card](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf) could be helpful for finding functions for different operations.

It is hard to know what problems you are running into, and why. You could for instance try to change number of digits shown in your values by: `options(digits=7)` to see if you can find the cause.

Furthermore, you can use `round` and `signif` functions depending on your data, see examples below:

```
> round(123.786582307,digits=8)%in%round(123.786582308,digits=8)
[1] TRUE

> round(3.786582307,digits=8)%in%round(3.786582308,digits=8)
[1] TRUE

> signif(123.786582307,digits=11)%in%signif(123.786582308,digits=11)
[1] TRUE

> signif(3.786582307,digits=9)%in%signif(3.786582308,digits=9)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Dear nadizan thank you for your answer, However, I used your mentioned functions. Yea, they are working this kind of data. As, I understand from my data, include large decimal value like after dot(.) it has 9 digit number. and when I compare this value like 123.786582307 with 123.786582308, it does not produce data. Do you have any idea about this problem?I use round() function. No luck. thank you

Comment: How did you generate your data? How come that the numbers vary? Is that what you expect? What accuracy do you want in your matching? You could do many different things, see the example above.@user6729255

Comment: it worked!! thank you nadizan!                                               groundT[,1:3] <-round(groundT[,1:3],digits=3) #the "-1" includes  column 1:3

lidar[,13:14] <- round(lidar[,13:14],digits=3)

matching <- which(lidar$X %in% groundT$X & lidar$Y %in% groundT$Y)